# TICKscripts not be triggered on other server?

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I wrote an TICKscript. It will be trigger on docker enviroment but no function on CentOS server, can somebody help me? and here is the script:

```
var name = 'timeout alert'

var data = stream
    |from()
        .database('db')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('part')
        .where(lambda: "type" == 'timeout')
    |eval(lambda: "value")
        .as('value')

var alert = data
    |alert()
        .id(name)
        .message('{{ .ID }}')
        .crit(lambda: "value" >= 60)
        .log('/tmp/alert.txt')

var trigger = data
    |eval(lambda: float("value"))
        .as('value')
        .keep()
    |influxDBOut()
        .create()
        .database('chronograf')
        .retentionPolicy('autogen')
        .measurement('alerts')
        .tag('alertName', name)
        .tag('triggerType', 'threshold')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found all stream tickscript didn't be triggered but don't know why. can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's a configuration problem. It's fixed after I reinstall the kapacitor use the default configure.